# Selenium IDE locator doesn't work in Selenium 3.3.1 Java

Tags: java, css, selenium, ide, fluentlenium

I have a web page which contains 2 links with the same classnames but with different div classes. The first one is invisible (it's in a dropdown menu) and the other one that I want is visible.
So, I'm trying to locate the visible element.

His HTML :

```
 <div class="mainActionPanel">
   <a css="create"></a>
 </div>
```

The link has a dynamic ID. When I do a XPath search with the ID, I find rightly the element but it's deprecated because the button hasn't the same ID on each page.

I tried to locate the element with Selenium IDE, the following locator worked : `css=div.mainActionPanel > a.create`

The problem is with the locator that I showed above.
When I try to find the element, I always have this exception :

> NoSuchElementException : Element By.cssSelector: css=div.mainActionPanel > a.create (first) (LazyElement) is not present.

He doesn't find it. I tried several syntax like an example in the FluentLenium documentation (`$("form > input[data-custom=selenium]"`) but it doesn't worked.

Moreover, the `el(".create").click()` is throwing an ElementNotVisibleException because he selects the dropdown link.

How can I find the right element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below:

```
 WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.mainActionPanel > a"));
 WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elem));

 elem.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this should help you..

```
 // this will provide you list of web elements based on class name
 List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findElements(By.className("mainActionPanel"));
```

Then you have to find out the required element by iterating through the list, like below.

```
  WebElement tempElement = null;
  for (WebElement element : webElements) {

            if (element.getAttribute("css").equals("create")) {
                tempElement = element;
            }
        }
```

Full code as follow,

```
  List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findElements(By.className("mainActionPanel"));

  WebElement tempElement = null;
  for (WebElement element : webElements) {

            if (element.getAttribute("css").equals("create")) {
                tempElement = element;
            }
  }


  //then you can perform that you want
  tempElement.click();
```

Comment: Doesn't works, the web elements list is null => NullPointerException

Comment: Have you tried this way, and before finding element give timer for atleast 4-5sec
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.cssName("create"));

here don't give class name as ".create"

Comment: Seems that the if condition is never true so tempElement stays null and it throws the exception.

Comment: If condition will only be executed if and only if element is in the list, otherwise it will not executed.

Comment: There are 3 elements in the list, I ran it in debug mode and there's a problem with the if condition cuz it throws the NullPointer.

Comment: Try this instead of taking list,
 WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.cssName("create");

and dont give "create" as ".create"

Comment: ElementNotVisibleException, he tries to take the first one but it's invisible... like I said for el(".create"), moreover el("create") isn't working either :/

Answer (score 0):

Changed from css search to xpath using :

```
xpath = (//a[contains(@href, '#')])[5]
```

Because it's the 4th "a" element with an href attribute which contains the text "#". No more trouble.

Look at this :
http://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html